# When trying to access Jira Client from Pycharm. I am getting 'response text = Basic auth with password is not allowed on this instance' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

Error Description = 'Basic auth with password is not allowed on this instance'.

Code:

```
from jira.client import JIRA

 options = {'server': 'https://organization.atlassian.net/'}
 jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('email@xxx.com', 'Password'))
```

WorkAround : Created try and catch block but got the same error.

Comment: It seems that the error message is your answer: the Jira server you are talking to is not configured to allow 'basic authentication'.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on where I need to configure ?

Comment: Read the docs here: https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#authentication